# NoClassDefFoundError in Hadoop setup

Tags: hadoop

I am using this guide to set up Hadoop:

http://blog.sqltrainer.com/2012/01/installing-and-configuring-apache.html

However when I get to the part where I'm supposed to type `bin/hadoop version` I get these errors:

```
cygpath: can't convert empty path
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" cygpath: can't convert empty path
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Hadoop 0.22.0
```

I recently was using version 1.0.3 and I got it working fine but I had to downgrade to version 0.22.0 because of a bug. Unfortunately I can't get this version to work.

More info:

```
JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/Java/jre6
```

Comment: Without any futher information, my guess is you should probably look into the `cygpath: can't convert empty path` exception / error / warnings you have in that output. Can you share the values of the HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables.

Comment: Does `bin/hadoop classpath` display the active classpath, or does that error too?

Comment: `bin/hadoop classpath` returns the same error. I added my JAVA_HOME in my original post. Where would I find HADOOP_HOME?

Comment: HADOOP_HOME should be set by the hadoop-config.sh. After you added in JAVA_HOME (in `$HADOOP/conf/hadoop-env.sh`), do you still see the same error?

Comment: I already had JAVA_HOME set before I started getting this error. What does HADOOP_HOME need to be set to?

Comment: You don't need to set it. Can you confirm that JAVA_HOME has been set in the hadoop-env.sh file?

Comment: What shell are you using? (bash, dash, ??)

Comment: Can you execute `sh -x $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop version` and dump the output to pastebin or something like that (be sure to replace HADOOP_HOME with the fully qualified path of your hadoop installation)?

Comment: I'm using cygwin. Here is the output:  http://pastebin.com/N48Vu7uK

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error when installing on windows/cygwin
open $HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/hadoop-config.sh in the editor of your choice.
Locate the section starting with "# cygwin path translation" and add the following line :

```
    CLASSPATH=`cygpath -wp "$CLASSPATH"`
```

Save and exit.

The fix worked for me.For more look into this blog

http://juliensimon.blogspot.in/2011/01/installing-hadoop-on-windows-cygwin.html

Answer (score 1):

Form your pastebin, looks like you have a problem with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable:

```
++ JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=
++ '[' -d 'C:\cygwin\usr\local\hadoop\/build/native' -o -d 'C:\cygwin\usr\local\                      hadoop\/lib/native' ']'
cygwin warning:
 MS-DOS style path detected: C:\cygwin\usr\local\hadoop\/build/native
 Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /usr/local/hadoop/build/native
 CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
 Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
   http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
```

Should this path by a cygwin path (`/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/local/hadoop/build/native`), and make sure the slashes are the right way.

perform a grep for the string `LD_LIBRARY` or `native` in your bin and conf folders to see where you potentially have this set wrong