# Error in hive start up - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am trying to start Hive in CDH 4.2 and I am running into the below issue

```
hive
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/RunJar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.  Program will exit.
```

Giving below are the environment parameters for reference. Am I missing something?

> echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR /etc/hadoop/conf/conf.pseudo
>
> echo $HADOOP_HOME /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce
>
> echo $CLASSPATH
>   /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core.jar;/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar;/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/*.*;
>
> echo $HIVE_HOME

Let me know if you would like to review any other environment variable that I may be missing here.

Comment: Check this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076964/noclassdeffounderror-in-hadoop-setup

Comment: After posting, I fixed it by appropriately pointing HIVE_HOME 
to '/usr/lib/hive/conf'